# Cual es mi error en el problema de arboles?

Tags: javascript, javascript-metodo

tengo el siguiente árbol de objetos:

La idea del ejercicio es contar las veces que aparezca el nombre repetido del arbol y guardarlo en ese acumulador. Por ejemplo como zapato aparece 4 veces deberia retornar ["Zapato", "Zapato", "Zapato", "Zapato"]

Cual es mi error? en cada if estoy preguntando si en ese objeto incluye el nombre que busco, esta bien planteado?

```
                 { nombre: "Camiseta", num: 13 }
                      /                           \
       {nombre: "Zapato", num: 7}          {nombre: "Camiseta", num: 24}
                   /                               /                 \
       {nombre: "Pollera", num: 6}   {nombre: "Zapato", num: 16}  {nombre: 27, num: 27}
                 /                                                     \
    {nombre: "Zapato", num: 3}                              {nombre: "Zapato", num: 45}
                  \
              {nombre: "Zapato", num: 4}
```

Este es mi planteo de codigo:

```
BinarySearchTree.prototype.obtenerPrendas = function (objeto) {
  var acumulador = [];

  if (this.value.includes(objeto.nombre)) {
    acumulador.push(this.value);
  }
  if (this.left !== null && this.left.includes(objeto.nombre)) {
    acumulador.push(this.value);
  }
  if (this.right !== null && this.right.includes(objeto.nombre)) {
    acumulador.push(this.value);
  }

  return acumulador;
};

BinarySearchTree.obtenerPrendas(Zapato);
```

Comment: Estás preguntando dos veces si left tiene algo, te olvidaste al copiar y pegar cambiar por right. Por otro lado, en un BST no debería haber valores repetidos, por lo que no entiendo el propósito del array acumulador

Comment: Ahi lo cambie y plantee mejor el enunciado xd

Comment: Si left y right son a su vez instancias de la clase BST, cómo está definido el método includes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error que veo en tu código es que solamente te encuentras evaluando si la raíz (El objeto que se encuentra en cabeza del árbol) y sus hojas izquierda y derecha tienen el nombre del objeto, más no haces un recorrido completo sobre el árbol evaluando todos los objetos del mismo.

De esta manera sería posible recorrer el árbol y evaluar si cada uno de los objetos tiene el objeto a buscar o no:

```
BinarySearchTree.prototype.obtenerPrendas = function (objeto) {
  var acumulador = [];

  //Verifica si la raíz del arbol tiene el objeto o no.
  if (this.value.includes(objeto.nombre)) {
    acumulador.push(this.value);
  }
  
  //Verifica que el ramaje izquerdo del arbol no sea nulo para así realizar una busqueda recursiva
  if (this.left !== null){
    acumulador.push(this.left.obtenerPrendas(objeto));
  }

  //Verifica que el ramaje derecho del arbol no sea nulo para así realizar una busqueda recursiva
  if (this.right !== null){
    acumulador.push(this.right.obtenerPrendas(objeto));
  }

  return acumulador.flat();
}
```

Como verás esta función se encuentra construida recursivamente, tal que evalua si la raíz del árbol tiene el objeto en cuestión o no, para acto seguido evalua si los ramajes izquierdos y derechos no están vacíos para así realizar el llamado de la misma función evaluando ahora los ramajes respectivos, y terminando cada llamado de la función cuando sus ramajes izquierdos y derechos han terminado.